# boost::any can't be casted back std::function

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to cast a function pointer stored in `boost::any` back to a function pointer.

```
void foo(int, int) {}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void bar(T func, Ts... args)
{
    boost::any any = func;

    boost::any_cast<std::function<void(Ts...)>>(any)(args...);
}
```

But `boost::any_cast` throws a `boost::bad_any_cast`, but I have no idea why, because the types are identical.

I am calling `bar` as follows

```
bar(foo, 0, 1);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: _"I have no idea why, because the types are identical."_ What's identical about them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you cast back a `boost::any`, you must cast back to precisely the same type. You cannot store a `void (*)(int, int)` and cast to a `std::function<void(int, int)>`.

You can change either what you store or what you cast to so that they match, and it should work.

Comment: For some reason I though they were the same, but I guess they are only *technically* the same... Thanks

Comment: @Rakete1111 They're very much technically different. They might be similar in your head, but that doesn't count.

Comment: @Rakete1111 You really think so? Check [here](http://pastebin.com/r1qdEWPe) for an example of a use of `std::function` that has no function pointer analog -- a `struct` with an `operator()`. Use of `std::bind` is another example. A `std::function` represents something invokable which may or may not be anything like a function pointer.

Comment: That's interesting, now I know :) Thank you